# How to pass an component/element reference from within the template?

Tags: angular

I have a single page with some tall elements. When I click on a button in the navigation I want to scroll to that element.

```html
<nav>
  <button type="button" (click)="scrollToSection(history)">History</button>
  <button type="button" (click)="scrollToSection(team)">Team</button>
</nav>

<app-history #history></app-history>
<app-team #team></app-team>
```

Currently passing in the element reference in the template like this seems to give me a reference to the component class, not the element. This is all I get when I log it out to the console

```txt
Object { __ngContext__: 1 }
```

Within my TS if I use

```ts
@ViewChild('history', {read: ElementRef}) historyEl!: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('team', {read: ElementRef}) teamEl!: ElementRef;

scrollToSection(el: any): void {
  console.log(el, this.historyEl, this.teamEl);
}
```

Now when I can get access to the `this.historyEl.nativeElement` property, but I have no way of matching up the passed in `el` with one of the `ViewChild` elements.

How can I pass in an element reference from within the template only? I would prefer to skip the `ViewChild` selection stuff as I only need to access `nativeElement` on whatever was passed into my method.

Comment: does my post answer your question? I've corrected it

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue and found a workaround.

let say you have this parent html

```
<div click="onClick(history)"></div>
<app-history #history></app-history>
```

and a `HistoryComponent.ts`

you could get the `elementRef` from the component and access it through parent

```
class HistoryComponent {

  constructor ( public elRef:ElementRef<HTMLElement>){}

}
```

then in parent component

```
class ParentComponent {

  ...

  onClick = ( component:HistoryComponent ) {

    component.elRef.nativeElement //HTML element here

  }

}
```